# (iphone) InAppSettings/InAppSettingsKit library questions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, setting, inappsettingskit

It seems there are many advocates of InAppSettings https://bitbucket.org/keegan3d/inappsettings/wiki/Home

In my app, I need to have multiple different settings page from different views.
(Conceptually there are multiple apps within the app, and each app needs its own setting page)

I thought maybe there will be some easy way to create settings page without IB or enourmous coding, and surely found InAppSettings and InAppSettingsKit( http://inappsettingskit.com/)

I have 2 concerns before digging into one of them.

1. Is it possible to create multiple settings page as mentioned above for one app?
2. I don't like apps that create settings entry in the iPhone settings app, I just want the settings appear inside my app only, is this possible with the two libraries?
3. (very optional) would be nice to be able to show an image when there are huge empty spaces below all the settings in a given setting page.

Thank you.

Comment: In regards to your second question, what do the words in "**in-app** settings" tell you?

Comment: @Jasarien , Quote from their site: InAppSettings provides a view controller that displays the application's Settings.bundle as it appears in the iPhone settings. Allowing the same preferences in app and in the iPhone settings.
"in the iPhone settings" part surprises you as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about InAppSettings, but InAppSettingsKit is able to do all three demands.
To do (2), just create a bundle named InAppSettings.bundle instead of the usual Settings.bundle.

For (1): Create .plists with different names inside the InAppSettings.bundle and have their name in the _file attribute of the IASKAppSettingsViewController.

For (3): The Custom View Controller (IASKAppSettingsViewController) it specifies is highly customizeable, and you can just read the code to see how they present the CreditsFooter to place your custom image.

Sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 1):

InAppSettingKit is designed to give you (alost)identical functionality to that of Settings.App.

As @Artur Sampaio says, you should create a separate *appname*.plist for each of your conceptual apps and then in your Settings.bundle add for each 'conceptual app' a PSChildPaneSpecifier that points to the *appname*.plist