# Different setting for InAppSettingKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, inappsettingskit

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162471/how-to-have-2-different-setting-page-with-inappsettings) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322404/iphone-inappsettings-inappsettingskit-library-questions) and also other questions related to `InAppSettingsKit`, but couldn't reach to the solution.
I have downloaded [LinPhone](http://www.linphone.org/) in which [InAppSettingsKit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit) is used for setting. Now, my requirement is I have to change the settings for only one particular case after login and it will be as it is for all the other cases.
Please guide me, how can I change settings for that one case and where?

Comment: be more specific on your question otherwise you might get `-ve` votes.

Comment: Please be more specific, it's not clear what you want.

Comment: You mean which plist you have to modify?

Comment: @VaibhavSaran please check updated question again.

Comment: @dimimpou No, I know which plist I have to modify. But how can I do this at run time?

Comment: @PiyushDubey sorry for late. All you want is to modify the settings programmatically?

Comment: @dimimpou yes.. but have no idea how can I do this and where(I mean which class)?

Comment: @PiyushDubey are you ok with my answer, cause i don't see any feedback..

Comment: @dimimpou well, I tried it, but it didn't work in my actual project. Might be the problem is in the open source code that I am using.

Comment: Can you specify what do you mean it didn't work?

Comment: I'am using this in 2 projects and works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief example:

```
// The name of the settings file, currently this plugin use the InAppSettings.bundle
NSString *settingsBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"InAppSettings" ofType:@"bundle"];
if(!settingsBundle) {
    NSLog(@"Could not find Settings.bundle");
    return;
}

NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[settingsBundle stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Root~iphone.inApp.plist"]];
NSArray *preferences = [settings objectForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"];

NSMutableDictionary *defaultsToRegister = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[preferences count]];
for(NSDictionary *prefSpecification in preferences) {
    NSString *key = [prefSpecification objectForKey:@"Key"];
    if(key) {
        [defaultsToRegister setObject:[prefSpecification objectForKey:@"DefaultValue"] forKey:key];
    }
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultsToRegister];
[defaultsToRegister release];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

So this you can place it in your AppDelegate on lunch to get the settings.
And then you can change a value associated with a key using `NSUserDefaults`

**Example of retrieve**:

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    CGFloat fontSize = 15;

    if(standardUserDefaults){
        fontSize = (CGFloat)[[standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"fontSize"] floatValue];
        if(fontSize == 0)
            fontSize = 15;
    }
```

**Notify Controller on Settings Change**

To see if some settings modified put this in your `viewDidLoad` of the Controller that you want to be notified:

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(defaultsChanged:)
               name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
             object:nil];
```

And you have only to implement the function `defaultsChanged`.

Comment: Let me know if you want any further help.

Comment: @PiyushDubey Does my answer help you? You didn't add a comment or accept it, although this is the way which this plugin works. In this way you don't help SO's users, you know that i thought.

Comment: well, if the answer had helped me, then I would have accepted. I had explained you in chat about the issue and I am still working on the problem. I really appreciate your answer, but it didn't work for me and I am totally aware about SO users and to help them. You can't force to accept your answer unless it had help you.